# How to determine Output format of a template in Content Delivery

Tags: content-delivery

I have a use case where I need to determine if a particular template on the Content Delivery side has the output format of `REL`.

The reason is because I'm trying to determine whether to use the `ComponentPresentationFactory` or the `ComponentPresentationAssember` for my evil deeds.

On the CM we set the Output Format on a Component Template as follows:

[image]

On the CD side, it is not obvious how to leverage this parameter.

The CD API's `ComponentPresentationFactory` has a method `GetComponentPresentationWithOutputFormat`, e.g.:

```
var cp = cpFactory.GetComponentPresentationWithOutputFormat(tcmUri.ItemId, "REL");
```

This tells me that the information about a CT's output format is stored on the CD side.

(As a side thought/question, I may have multiple CTs for a given component that are REL. So what which one would the above method return, the highest priority one, or the first one it finds?)

Another supporting argument that the `OutputFormat` exists on the CD side is that the `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.ITemplateMeta` interface has a `OutputFormat` property as per the documentation.  But I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get an instance of `ITemplateMeta` based on a template ID.

I am trying to avoid having to publish any XML or JSON files from the CM with a listing of REL templates because that just seems hacky.

Can anyone please shed some light on how to get the OutputFormat on the CD side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
using (var ctTypeCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(32))
{
      using (var idCriteria = new ItemReferenceCriteria(3148))
      {
           var ctAndIdCriteria = new AndCriteria(ctTypeCriteria, idCriteria);
           var outputFormat = ((ITemplateMeta)new Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Query(andCrit).ExecuteEntityQuery().First()).OutputFormat;
      }
}
```